# "As on 16 May" vs. "as of 16 May" — which is correct?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions

I updated a cost sheet and I want to specify that it's a newly updated cost sheet.
For this situation, which one is correct?

> cost sheet as **on/of** 16 May

Before specifying a date, which will come first, *on* or *of*?

Comment: They are both correct for different situations. For example, *As on 16 May, he again failed to arrive at work on time.*  and *As of 16 May he will have worked here for a full year.*

Comment: @Athi - Research work means have you tried to search for the solution of your problem on the web or other sources?

Comment: @Athi What we ask is that you describe the effort you made, and it is best to put that description into the question itself instead of comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are both correct but mean different things in different situations. *As of May 16* indicates the start of something; from that time on, while *as on May 16* is completely different. *As* in *as on May 16* means *such as; like* and is used for comparison.

> As of May 16, 2012 cigarettes are banned in this country.
>
> As *on* May 16, he again failed to attend the conference.

Back to your specific example. In your case *as of* makes more sense because you want to say that the sheet covers cost from *May 16* on.

Answer (score 1):

"as of" is the same as "as from": used to show the time/date from which something starts, e.g. As of/from Monday, we shall give all of you winning bonuses.

Comment: Supporting your answer with sources makes it stronger and more likely to be viewed as correct. Otherwise, it's likely to be viewed as only opinion (which is worth less on this Q&A site). The [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) will give you guidance on how to use this site.

Answer (score -1):

There is no difference. Both indicate a situation that exists at a particular time--whether it begins from that time or ended at that time is moot.

Comment: This would benefit from some supporting examples.